# Privacy of subscribing to a Facebook page's events (without liking the page)

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-events, facebook-privacy, facebook-subscriptions

I would like to be notified about the new events created by a Facebook page:

[image: facebook page events]

But I don't want anyone to know I have ever seen this page, so in particular I cannot "like" it.
Is it possible?

I noticed this "Subscribe" button:

[image: Facebook page subscribe]

If I were to click it, would this action or subscription be visible to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Facebook Support](https://facebook.com/help/1549689361910442) your friends will see when you subscribe to a page's events. You may want to traverse through your profile's privacy options to see if there is a way to disable that sharing.